# java: taking input with BufferedReader- more than one spaces

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader, spaces

I have space separated integers in one line and want to input them using BufferedReader. ** **There may be more than one spaces between the integers. There may be leading and trailing spaces****

Right now I have following code ,

`

```
  int[] a = new int[1000001]; // integer array

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

  int n; // no of integers

  int n =  Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

  String[] s = br.readLine().split(" ");  //taking input

      for(int i=1;i<=n;++i)
      {

           a[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
      }
```

`

Its not working.Please help. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated . Thanks.

**Edit:1 - I used split("\s+"). But this cares for more than one spaces between integers... What about leading and trailing spaces..?? How to deal with them..?**

Comment: `Its not working.` what exactly is not working? Do you get any errors? Any exception? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this - java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: That means there was a parsing error. Are you allowed to use a [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)?

Comment: But scanner is slow , that's why I am avoiding using scanner. But If you know how to do it with scanner ,that will be also helpful .Thanks

Comment: 'Scanner is slow' compared to what? You don't have anything to compare it with, and you haven't measured Scanner either. So your statement is meaningless.

Comment: @EJP - I mean scanner is slow in comparison to BufferedReader . And I have to input numbers around 10^5 in one second .

Comment: You should change your for loop, in java arrays start a index 0 and also you should make sure that the `s` array contains enough elements. So the for-loop should be `for(int i=0; i < n && i < s.length; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split("\\s+")` it should do the trick. It tells `split()` to use one or more space characters as a delimiter between two tokens.

Also you should allocate you int[] after you have read the number of int to read instead of allocating one that is way too big, you waste memory for nothing

Comment: I used split("\\s+"). But this cares for more than one spaces between integers... What about leading and trailing spaces..?? How to deal with them..?

Comment: use `br.readLine().trim().split("\\s+")` it will remove the leading and trailing spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the line, then use a regex to replace all whitespace with only one space. Then you can split it as you do above. Let me know if you need further help or code examples.

Edit: the NumberFormatException could be because the Integer.parseInt is trying to parse something outside of the value of an integer. Try Long.parseLong instead.

Comment: I have never used "regex" .So, can you provide a little peace of code?

Comment: "\\s+" is an example of regex which means 1 or more whitespaces.